# setNextApproverIds can not set Guest user

Tags: apex, lightning

```
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req.setComments('submit!');
req.setObjectId(acc.id);
req.setSubmitterId(acc.OwnerId); 
req.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('ExternalApproval_V2');
req.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{extUser.Id});
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);
```

1. Use the system administrator user to modify the record.
2. After modifying the record, enter the before trigger and execute the above code.
   The system returned an exception

[image]

3. The guest user clicks the Sites Visualforce Page approve button
4. Enter the Visualforce PAGE controller, execute the above code,
   System executed successfully
   [image]

I can use the **site Visualforce Page** to set it.
The field setNextApproverIds in the Controller is set to UserInfo.getUserId(). The screenshot has been successful.
What I need now is to set the guest user in the trigger. I think that since it can be set in the site page, there should be a way to implement it in the trigger?

Comment: the guest user is effectively an anonymous user and shared by all such real people accessing a Site anonymously so by definition, they should not be able to approve anything

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Guest users cannot be set up as approvers (*Guest user profile/ license is highly restrictive in nature and is intended to control public or unauthenticated access to community data*), but external users with Customer Community plus or Partner licenses can be. [Salesforce help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_approvals_for_external_users.htm&type=5) states the following:

> Customer Community Plus and Partner users in your community can be
> assigned as approvers on records or added directly to queues.

Comment: Hi @arut I updated the content

Comment: So, looks like _Guest User_ might actually have a valid community license & profile. Could you mention what license and profile has been assigned to this user? Also, when does this piece of code execute (like upon click of some button etc.)?

Comment: User License = Guest License,  In the trigger (before update) to meet the judgment condition execution

Comment: The user license you are having is contradicting the SF documentation. I might have to replicate this problem at my end before making any further comments. And, about the trigger part, I meant to ask what action is causing the trigger? There must be something like user is updating certain fields. Actually, it would make sense if you improved the question with some steps to replicate this problem.

Comment: Hi @arut Thank you  I have described the detailed steps.